# Replace Content that match RegExp in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, str-replace

I want to find specific content that match with regexp from whole page and then need to replace with another text. Here is my code which I'm using.

```
 var reg = /exam+ple/;
    $("body").html(function () {
        return $(this).html().replace(reg, "exammmmmmmmple"); 
    });

  // html
  <body>
     This is some example text<br/>
     exammmple.com
     <a href="http://example.com"> Visit a site </a>
     <div id="example"> Here is some other text</div>
  </body>
```

The code which I used work but there is one problem it can't replace content which is inside `href` and `id` I want changes everywhere where the match of regExp.

And there is another problem this code is slow because first you take whole body content then you make changes to it and then you insert content again in body, is there any other way to fast it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could iterate trough the nodes. One way to do so is using the nodeIterator. An example of this could look like the following snippet.

#### edit

*(since you not only want to replace text)*

With this solution it won't get better than changing each property of the currentNode.
I adjusted the snippet below to also change the attribute href. You can always iterate trough all attributes - for example if you want to change them all.

---

#### suggestion

I strongly suggest looking at

- difference between Nodes / Elements.
- `https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node`
- `https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeIterator`

to optimize the snipped for your use case.

---

#### trick to work with nodes

In the developer tools of chrome you can go to the `Elements` tab right click on the element you want to see the properties of and click `copy -> Copy selector`. Now you go to the `Sources` tab. On the right you'll see a `Watch` section. Open it and put the following snippet there:

`document.querySelector('PASTE YOU SELECTOR HERE');`

---

#### example snippet

```
let currentNode;
const nodeIterator = document.createNodeIterator(document.body, NodeFilter.SHOW_ALL);

while(currentNode = nodeIterator.nextNode()) {
  if(currentNode.nodeType == Node.ELEMENT_NODE && currentNode.attributes.href) {
    currentNode.attributes.href = currentNode.attributes.href.replace(/someText/g, 'foo');
  }
  if(currentNode.nodeType == Node.TEXT_NODE) {
    currentNode.nodeValue = currentNode.nodeValue.replace(/someText/g, 'foo');
  }
}
```

Comment: This is good for performance but this is not work with link it didn't change the `href` link In this case it need to change it like `href="http://example.com"` to `href="http://foo.com"`. It change the link text but not actual link.

Comment: I adjusted the answer - I hope it shows you how to approach your problem.

Answer (score 2):

Use [global modifier(`g`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/global#Using_global) with regex to replace all occurrence.

```
var reg = /exam+ple/g;
```

```js
var reg = /exam+ple/g;
$("body").html(function(_, htm) {
  return htm.replace(reg, "exammmmmmmmple");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  This is some example text<br/> exammmple.com
  <a href="http://example.com"> Visit a site </a>
  <div id="example"> Here is some other text</div>
</body>
```

---

**FYI :** It's really a bad idea to update the entire HTML since which recreates all the elements and that would destroy all the attached event handlers since elements are recreated.

Comment: But how can I make it fast

Comment: @PakDeveloper : for that, you need to get all the individual nodes(recursively) and update all attributes and contents

Comment: if you want to walk trough the nodes you might want to have a look at this one too: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createNodeIterator